# position saving with simulation nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

Ever since simulation nodes came out, I have been wondering would it be possible to store information from a previous frame to use in animation. I'm quite new to the geometry nodes side of blender, so I was wondering if someone could show me how to create an effect using simulation nodes.

Here is the inspiration for what I'm trying to do, however I'm not 100% sure if this example uses simulation nodes.
https://twitter.com/Bbbn192/status/1591493734532845573
[image]

The idea of this effect would be to take the position of the previous frame, save it, then display it with a noise modifier.
Here is a diagram of what I want to do, where the blue Suzanne is the current position and the red Suzanne would be the previous position with the noise effect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am 99% sure it does ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

to get this result:

[image]

---

update:

[image]

your connection must be from frame to value (first input), not in the second one.

result after plugging the noodle in the right input:

[image]

Comment: sorry for bothering you for about your answer, but I can't seem to replicate your results for some reason it's probably me being stupid but here is a gif of what I currently have. https://media.giphy.com/media/twT9WNhUde4qUoHPRK/giphy.gif

 Also, I have a question about whether you could get the previous saves to eventually disappear as an example, could you have the node setup were it only ever show 2 save points and have the others behind that disappear? Sorry, I should have stated this in the original question, just dint realize I needed that.

Comment: i am sorry but i cannot recognize anything in your gif. pls provide blend file so i can check it out

Comment: i just can assume that you just "animated" the cube. Delete the cube animation. Create a rig (just a single bone) for your cube, then parent your cube to that armature. Then animate the bone in pose mode. Make sure the GN modifier is after the armature.

Comment: Yes, your assumption was correct, I was only animating the cube and not rigging it. Adding a bone made the animation work, however for some reason the node setup is making the distance between the frame saves none linear unlike your example. I changed the animation interpolation to liner, but that did not seem to help, probably something else I could be doing wrong 

https://imgur.com/a/t8YtdXJ

Comment: This depends on your animation. If it is not linear, of course the distance is not equal. But since you did post only an image - i can only guess. So pls upload a blend file if you want to know the reason why it is that way.

Comment: sorry I should have done that to begin with, the blend file is now on the blend file attached to the main question

Comment: i updated my answer